# Need helping knowing how to process this data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I need to sort this data in Google Sheets. I have names and then each name has 4 letters assigned to it, one in each column.

An example is I need to know everyone who has a T and an I in column B and C. Or everyone who is D and E in column F and G.
I've hid the names in column A.

Can someone tell me what functions to use to do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. There are many "functions". You could use filter, filter views, pivot tables, fomrmula functions like FILTER, QUERY, VLOOKUP, function combinations like using MATCH and INDEX and maybe others. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to using excel/sheets so wasn't even sure where to start. I am happy to teach myself a formula or function, I just need to know what people think would be the most effective in this situation.

Comment: I already mentioned several functions. Please look for them in the Help menu or the formula bar of Google Sheets. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].